# Why getObjectType() method of FactoryBean does not invoked by the IOC Container

Tags: java, spring

> As we know `java.util.Calendar` class is an abstract class so that IOC Container cannot create the object of this class. Hence we can take the help of either **Static factory method instantiation** or implementing the **FactoryBean** interface and override the 3 methods *getObject(), getObjectType() and isSingleton()*. But before Spring 2.0 **Static factory method instantiation** is not available.

Now we will take the help of FactoryBean while creating the obejct of `java.util.Calendar` class.

> This is my **CalendarFactoryBean** class

```
package com.fb.helper;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;

public class CalenderFactoryBean implements FactoryBean{

@Override
public Class getObjectType() {
    System.out.println("getObjecType method called");
    return Calendar.class;
}

@Override
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("getObject method called");
    return calendar;
}

@Override
public boolean isSingleton() {  
    System.out.println("isSingleton method called");
    return true;
    }   
}
```

> This is my `application-context.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="calendar" class="com.fb.helper.CalenderFactoryBean"/> 
</beans>
```

> This is my `Test.java` class

```
package com.fb.test;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BeanFactory beanFactory=new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("com/fb/common/application-context.xml"));
    
    Calendar calendar=beanFactory.getBean("calendar",Calendar.class);
    System.out.println(calendar);
}
}
```

And finally this is the output
[Click here to see the Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK2Sy.png)

> Now, My Question is **Why getObjectType() method of FactoryBean does not invoked by the IOC Container ???**